# Trigger to prevent Duplicate and add Add Task to Existing

Tags: trigger

I am trying to prevent duplicate Lead records from being created when users import Lead records into Salesforce that have the same email address.

Here is the scenerio:

1. A user imports leads using the Data Import Wizard
2. If the Lead being imported already exist in Salesforce the Lead from the spreadsheet will not be inserted into salesforce.  And the existing record that was found should have an activity added to it.

I have a Lead trigger below that either:

- Adds a task to the existing Lead but allows the duplicate to be created
- Or the duplicate will fail on insert but the task is never added to the existing Lead

The issue is that I am unable to stop duplicates from being imported into Salesforce and then creating a task on the existing Lead record that was found during the import process.

The trigger I have is below.

```
  trigger LeadPreventDuplicate on Lead (after insert,after update) {

Map<String, Lead> leadMap = new Map<String, Lead>();

  for (Lead lead : System.Trigger.new) 
  { 

   if ((lead.Email != null) && (System.Trigger.isInsert ||
        (lead.Email != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id).Email))) 
        {
          leadMap.put(lead.Email, lead);
        }
  }

  List<task> addtask=New List<task>();

  for (Lead lead : [SELECT Email FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :leadMap.KeySet()]) 
  {
    Lead newLead = leadMap.get(lead.Email);  // task being added to new Leads but should only be for existing leads
    addtask.add(new Task(
    WhoID =lead.id, 
    Status = 'Active',
    Subject = 'Test Task',
    ActivityDate = system.today()));

   } 
   insert addtask; 

   Lead[] dupes = new Lead[0];
      Set<String> email = new Set<String>(), dupEmail = new Set<String>();
          for(Lead record: Trigger.new)
          email.add(record.email);
          email.remove(null);
          for(Lead record: [SELECT Id, Email FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :email])
                if(!Trigger.newMap.containsKey(record.id))
                dupEmail.add(record.Email);
          for(Lead record: Trigger.new)
    if(dupEmail.contains(record.Email))
        dupes.add(record.clone(true));
    else
        dupEmail.add(record.Email);
delete dupes;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, what is the specific problem with the code you've shared here? Have you considered using Salesforce native duplicate management instead of code?

Comment: I second that you should *strongly consider* out-of-the-box **[Duplicate Management](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management)**.

Comment: Also just to note, you should not act on records other than `trigger.new` in any `before` context. Inserting new records should go in an `after` trigger.

Comment: I did look at the duplication management functionality but I need to be able to not only prevent a duplicate from being inserted but I need to add a task to the existing Lead.  For example an existing Lead record(1) has the email address test@gmail.com.  A user has a csv that has a record(2) where the email address is equal to test@gmail.com.  The import needs to fail and an activity record needs to be added to lead record(1).  Are you suggested I incorporate the Duplicate Management OTB functionality and a trigger? Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Created Matching and Duplicate rule to 'Block' on creation and edit.  Non Duplicate Leads went in and the Duplicates leads did not.  This is good except the task are never created on the existing Leads. Tried using Data Import Wizard within Salesforce using create and Add New and Update existing Records but the activities never showed on the existing Leads.

Comment: OK, so that helps with the broader context - can we circle back to the specific issue you'd like to get addressed with this code? It'll be helpful if you can edit this detail into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A user imports leads using the Data Import Wizard
>
> If the Lead being imported already exist in Salesforce the Lead from the spreadsheet will not be inserted into salesforce. And the existing record that was found should have an activity added to it.

These things are rather tricky to do together. As you have probably found, using
`addError()`

```
    newLead.Email.addError('A lead with this email address already exists!');
```

does block the Lead from being added, but it also results in a rollback of the transaction, and that rollback takes your new Task out with it. (I'm glossing over niceties of `allOrNone=false` here because you, as the trigger, cannot control whether you're running in an `allOrNone` context or not).

I think the simplest way to achieve this is to move your trigger operation to `after insert` and then *delete* the duplicate Leads, rather than trying to block them from being inserted in the first place. While there is a way to do the former, it'd involve bouncing the Ids of the "master" Leads into a different transaction via Platform Events to do the Task insertion (because posting a Platform Event is non-transactional), while using `addError()` to block the Leads from being inserted.

Taking the deletion approach: You can't perform DML directly on `Trigger.new` while in `after insert` context (the sObjects are read-only), but you can still delete them. This is legal, for example, if very weird:

```
if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
    List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
    for (Lead a : Trigger.new) {
        leads.add(new Lead(Id = a.Id));
    }
    delete leads;
}
```

Hence, if you switch to using `after insert` context, you can preserve your Task addition and your deletion of duplicate Leads in a single trigger.

I still don't really like this architecture. I think it's non-idiomatic and likely to cause behavior that, while correct, is unintuitive. But it's something you can do if you must.

Comment: David, thank for the suggestion.  I assumed that the Delete will happen after the task insertion.  Also, how would this process be cleaner?  Should the task insert and deletion be in separate triggers?

Comment: The cleanest solution is to use out-of-the-box duplicate management. I don't know where the add-a-Task requirement stems from so I can't comment on that, but if it's negotiable, I would push back.

Comment: We capture Customer engagements as Activities on the Lead record.  The lead record just houses the customer basic information while the activities record what the customer has done.  I updated the code that I am testing with in the original comment.  Activities are created to existing Lead but the New Leads did not get inserted.  I am assuming that this is because I changed the trigger to after insert/update.

Comment: That's because you had your trigger delete *all* of the new leads, rather than just the duplicates.

Comment: Ok I see that now.  But how do I find the inserted duplicates?  My initial query is to select the email addresses that are in the Lead object and compare them to the the values in the keyset.  I do not want to delete the values that are not in the keyset because those are the new non duplicate leads.  So do I need to query salesforce again to find newly created lead that have a matching email address?

Comment: You would need to iterate over the Leads you queried to create a collection, like a `Set` of their email addresses (squelching to lowercase because Set membership is case-sensitive). Then, iterate over the trigger Leads and see which ones have emails in the Set (similarly lowercasing). Those are the ones you need to delete.

Comment: This has definitely grown more complex than expected.  Tried using the set approach and received the following error "DML statement cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old"  Do I need to create another collection that does not reference "System.Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id).Email"?

Comment: That error is about the sObject instance, not the field value. I can't tell you the source without looking at your current code.

Comment: David, I updated the trigger based on a suggestion from a previous post.  So duplicates are not inserted and a task is added to the existing Leads within SF.  But task are being added to the newly created Leads and a task is being added to existing Leads even if a duplicate Lead was NOT being inserted.  Is the initial 'for' loop incorrect?